# Datagridview Column not in datatable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, calculated-columns

Is there any chance of adding a calculated column (a complex calculation, not possible to calculate in SQL) on a `DataGridView` (WinForms - vb.NET)?

I was hoping something like when I have in ASP.NET the `RowDataBound` Event of `GridView` control, but the way of link data of asp and vb are way too different.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I've given an answer that covers the most general approach to this but without any more info it is hard to be sure I have addressed your problem.

Comment: I think you got it, but it's early to know... i'll postback with news

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can add an unbound column to the grid:

```
Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
col.Name = "Unbound"
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)
```

And place the grid in VirtualMode:

```
DataGridView1.VirtualMode = True
```

Then use a handler for the CellValueNeeded event:

```
Private Sub CellValueNeeded(sender As System.Object, e As DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueNeeded
    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Unbound" Then
        e.Value = "Hi"
    End If
End Sub
```

In the handler above I just set the value to something trivial but you can add any calculation you like here.